# Disable TestNG Reporting for Specific Tests

Tags: java, testng

I've built an application to store `testng-results.xml` data in a database. However, I don't want tests with the annotation `@BeforeMethod` to be reported in the XML file in order to avoid persisting the data. Is there a way I can disable reporting based on annotation, or even the name of the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own reporter with your own logic. 
https://seleniumexperience.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/generating-custom-reports-with-testng/

Comment: This looks like what I'll have to do. Thanks!